# What is the Big Oh of new Set(arr1)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set, big-o

I was doing a small problem of **Finding common elements in two arrays**

```
function isCommonElementsPresent2(arr1,arr2){
   let set = new Set();

   for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
      set.add(arr1[i]);
   }

   for(let i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
     if(set.has(arr2[i])){
       console.log(arr2[i]);
     }
   }
}  //Big Oh of this is O(N+M)
```

Now if I solve the same problem as below

What will the Big-Oh become? Will it be same or will it change? What is Big-Oh of  `let set = new Set(arr1);`

```
function isCommonElementsPresent2(arr1,arr2){
   let set = new Set(arr1);

   for(let i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
     if(set.has(arr2[i])){
       console.log(arr2[i]);
     }
   }
}
isCommonElementsPresent2(["a","b","y","e","f"],["z","y","f"]);

//What is the Big-Oh of this code block?
```

Can someone guide me here?

Comment: It should be the same. `new Set(arr)` has to contain a loop similar to yours.

Comment: In both cases it's linear on average and quadratic worst-case.

Comment: @MoB. No, `Set`s have guaranteed sub-linear access time, so it won't ever be quadratic

Comment: @Bergi The sub-linear access time is guaranteed for the average/amortized case. Common implementations rely on hashing, so the worst-case complexity is indeed quadratic: namely in the unlikely case of always having hash collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computational complexity is the same. In both cases, each element of `arr1` needs to be iterated over to be put into the Set.

```
let set = new Set();
for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
  set.add(arr1[i]);
}
```

is similary expensive to

```
let set = new Set(arr1);
```